# Speed up code for referencing / importing data from SQL Server into Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, azure

I have a problem here that I will probably need to solve in several iterations, this being the first. maybe you have an idea:

I need to speed up regular updates from 4 views in an SQL database on Azure to an Excel Worksheet. There are probably a lot of moving parts here, among them: The code, my connection to the internet, the service that provides me with a static IP address, the fact that I reference views and not tables, and the (rather basic) service level I booked in Azure.

What my code does is simple: it opens a connection, updates 4 worksheets from 4 views (3 of them with 5 - 10 rowns of data, 1 with about 2.000), and closes the connection again.

This takes up to 30 seconds, which seems an awfully long time.

I would like to make sure it is not my code that slows this down. My first attemt was to  use Powerquery for the connections, call the connection, then set autofilters with VBA to have only the rows visible that I needed. That took ages.

My second try is: not use Powerquery, get rid of the autofilters, and use VBA instead to pass a SELECT to the SQL Server, so the work of selecting the data is done there, and send over only what I need. But it seems the difference that this makes is not really significant.

The code I use is:

```
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Set WS1 = Worksheets("Eingabe")
Dim SelectedCustomer As Range
Set SelectedCustomer = WS1.Range("C39")
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim SQLStr1 As String
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLStr2 As String
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLStr3 As String
Dim rs3 As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs3 = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLStr4 As String
Dim rs4 As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs4 = New ADODB.Recordset



'Open a connection to SQL Server - using the connection string provided by Azure
        

        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        cn.Open "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:server- 
        displacethis.database.windows.net,1433;Database=my-database;Uid=my-userID;Pwd=my- 
        password;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"


'First table


        SQLStr1 = "SELECT CustomerID,CustomerUniqueName,CustomerFirstName,CustomerLastName,TransactionDate,EmissionenNeukauf,EmissionenSecondhand,600 As DurchschnittDE, 300 As Paris2030 FROM vAccumulatedEmissionsByCustomer WHERE CustomerUniqueName = '" & SelectedCustomer & " ' "

        rs1.Open SQLStr1, cn, adOpenStatic

'Dump to spreadsheet

 With Worksheets("vAccumulatedEmissions").Range("A2:I100") 
          .ClearContents
          .CopyFromRecordset rs1


'Do some column formatting
 Worksheets("vAccumulatedEmissions").Range("F:F").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"


'Tidy up
        rs1.Close
        Set rs1 = Nothing



End With

'Then the next table follows. The connection os closed after the last table: 

        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing
```

My questions is, very simply, is this highly ineffective code, and could that be the reason for the long time it runs, or should I look somewhere else to speed up the whole process?

Thank you in advance,

Ulrich

Comment: I found a website (https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Latency) that claims to measure the latency time between my location and the Azure datacenter my stuff is hosted on, and the difference in latency  of me directly to my Azure datacenter vs. me via my static IP provider to my Azure datacenter is about 10 ms, so I guess no explanation for the 30 seconds in that direction

Comment: Azure shows query execution times in the ms area, so everything normal there, too I guess.

I changed all ranges that showed (for example) ("A:A") to defined ranges like ("A2:A5000"). Still no luck. Hope you guys and girls have some hints.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with that code - looks like a "regular" ADO approach.  If you leave out the 2000-row query is it faster?  You could add some timing code to see where that 30seconds is going.

Comment: Yes, thanks for this hint. The 2000-row query takes up about 80% of the time the 4 queries run, so I will focus my efforts on that.

Comment: Do the tables have appropriate indexes ?

Comment: CDP1802, I would have to check. Thanks for bringing that up